# Balanced sampling between classes in PyTorch

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, sampling

I'm splitting the data using PyTorch's `data.random_split`

```py
train_idx, validate_idx, test_idx = data.random_split(X, 
                         [num_training_sample, num_validation_sample, num_testing_sample])
```

Which returns the indexes for the random split. Then I'm doing the following

```py
train = [X[train_idx.indices], y[train_idx.indices]]
validate = [X[validate_idx.indices], y[validate_idx.indices]]
test = [X[test_idx.indices], y[test_idx.indices]]
```

Though they split have 6:2:2 ratio in total but the sampling between classes is not same. When I printed the counts, it shows

`{0: 4251, 1: 4168, 2: 4223, 3: 4192, 4: 4180, 5: 4133, 6: 4226, 7: 4249, 8: 4238, 9: 4140}`

Now, I can iterate over the samples and make balanced sub-samples, but I was wondering if there was a way in PyTorch(or Numpy) to do this efficiently.

Comment: You can use [Stratified K-Folds cross-validator](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold) from sklearn that preserving the percentage of samples for each class same as in data.